# Mypy complaining "unsupported right operand type for in ("object") and "object" has no attribute "get" but interpreter runs fine?

Tags: python, mypy

I have some really simply python code running and I don't understand why mypy is complaining about it. I am kind of new to using Python, so maybe it's obvious, but I haven't had much luck.

I have this dict:

```
    DEFAULTS = {
        "environments": {
            "beta": {
                "level": 10
            },
            "prod": {
                "level": 20
            }
        },
        "contact": {
            "username": "blah",
            "type": "test",
            "name": "blah2"
        }
    }
```

If I drop it in the interpreter and mess with it in the console, I can do things like

```
   stage = # get stage from somewhere
   if stage in DEFAULTS.get("environments"):
       # Do something
```

But if I do the same exact thing in my "real" code, I get a mypy error that says:
`error: Unsupported right operand type for in ("object")` .

Similarly, if I try to do:
`something = DEFAULTS.get("contact").get("username")`, it works just fine from my interpreter, but mypy says `error: "object" has no attribute "get"`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the type of object under the key `"environments"`?

Comment: In your real code where does the object come from? How is it created?

Comment: I define DEFAULTS the same way in the “real” code as in the interpreter (except in both cases I don’t set things to “blah”) . In the real code, I just create the dict at the beginning of my script

Comment: `mypy` infers `DEFAULTS` as `dict[str, object]` here. You can use a simple class for configuration, use `pydantic` model, or declare a nested `TypedDict` to annotate `DEFAULTS` if you have to retain dict-based configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `mypy` cannot infer the type of the items inside of `DEFAULT` dict so it assumes that `DEFAULT` contains objects, over which you cannot apply the `in` operator.

Adding explicit types to your declaration of the `DEFAULT` dictionary and checking that the return type of the `DEFAULT.get()` should fix it.

```
from typing import Dict, Union
DEFAULTS:Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[str, Dict[str, int]]]] = {
        "environments": {
            "beta": {
                "level": 10
            },
            "prod": {
                "level": 20
            }
        },
        "contact": {
            "username": "blah",
            "type": "test",
            "name": "blah2"
        }
    }
default_env = DEFAULTS.get("environments")
stage = # get stage from somewhere
if default_env is not None and stage in default_env:
        # Do something
```